# Set gitlab-ci.yml variable via bash command

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

```
variables:
  CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION: '$${cat .nvmrc}'
```

I'd like for the variable `CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION` to be populated via the contents of the `.nvmrc` file (which is located in the projects root directory). How does one do this in the `gitlab-ci.yml` file?

The example above isn't working. I've also tried the following:

- `CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION: $(cat .nvmrc)` -> `(cat .nvmrc)`
- `CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION: "$(cat .nvmrc)"` -> `(cat .nvmrc)`
- `CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION: '$(cat .nvmrc)'` -> `(cat .nvmrc)`
- `CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION: ${cat .nvmrc}` -> (empty string)
- `CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION: '${cat .nvmrc}'` -> (empty string)
- `CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION: "${cat .nvmrc}"` -> (empty string)

It works if I put it in the `before_script` like the following:

```
before_script:
  - CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION=$(cat .nvmrc)
```

But it isn't accessible to the following part of the `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
lint:
  stage: Test
  image: node:$CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION
```

Comment: Why can't you try normal command substitution syntax of `$(..)`. Note that `${..}` is for expanding variables, in your case though you needed to run commands. Can you do `CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION: $(cat .nvmrc)`

Comment: @Inian Yo! I did try this, however it results in the following: `(cat .nvmrc)`

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/34202 please upvote and leave a comment to pull more attention

Answer (score 10):

I also wanted to use a version string in a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file but for appending it to a Docker image name.  I did it like this:

```
build:
  stage: build_images
  script:
    - API_VERSION=v$(grep -E -o "(version = )(.*)" pyproject.toml | cut -d\" -f2)
    - echo $API_VERSION
    # Build and push new images for staging.
    - docker pull $API_STAGING:latest
    - docker build --cache-from $API_STAGING:latest >-
        -t $API_STAGING:latest >-
        -t $API_STAGING:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA >-
        -t $API_STAGING:$API_VERSION >-
        -f dockerfiles/Dockerfile.staging .
    - docker push $API_STAGING
  tags:
    - build
```

The key line here is `API_VERSION=v$(grep -E -o "(version = )(.*)" pyproject.toml | cut -d\" -f2)`.

Explanation: the string I'm trying to read in `pyproject.toml` is something like `version = "0.17.1"`, and the result I wanted was `v0.17.1`

- `v` is just a string I want to prepend to my version number
- `-E` (`--extended-regexp`) invokes `grep` as `egrep`; allows use of special regexp characters
- `-o` (`--only-matching`) doesn't make a difference in my use-case, but might be helpful in other cases (I'm not sure)
- `(version = )` and `(.*)`: the two capture groups; the latter one captures anything after the space after the equal sign
- Running just `$ grep -E -o "(version = )(.*)" pyproject.toml` will result in `version = "0.1.0"`, so I'm not using the capture groups; instead, I'm using `cut`
- `cut` "cut[s] out selected portions of each line of a file"
- `-d\"` sets the delimiter to a double-quote instead of the default (tab)
- `-f2` specifies the fields to return; a value of 1 would return everything before the first quote, i.e., `version =` , so 2 returns everything before the second quote and after the first, and 3 returns nothing in this example since there is no third double-quote-separated field
- `echo $API_VERSION` just to see that it's working

Comment: if your using poetry, you just need `poetry version -s` instead of the grep/cut.

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip!  In the example above, I'm not sure if I was already using Poetry when I first used the grep/cut, but it's clear I didn't know about that command when I started using it.  It's not clear to me that the Docker container would have access to the system Poetry install, though.

Comment: A more direct way is to use awk matching, and print the second field `awk -F\"  '/version/  {print $2}' pyproject.toml`

Comment: what if grep doesn't return any matching string, then cut command will crash

Answer (score 7):

There are some parts of `.gitlab-ci.yml` where variables are usable and some parts where they are not.

The `.yml` file is parsed in Gitlab itself and then the commands are executed by the runner. So setting a variable that is used in the job config is not possible at this point. You could use a pre-defined Secret Variable although that doesnot seem to fix your need.

There are issues tracking the documentation of what you can and cannot do:

- [Variables in docker service alias not supported](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/38136)
- [Document the list of places where you are allowed to use an env variable in .gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/38325)

Answer (score 7):

You might want to try:

```
before_script:
  - export CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION=$(cat .nvmrc)
```

In your script to make the variable available to subsequent shells.