# how can I set dynamic variable in gitlab ci/cd

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

dynamic variable by command
`curl http://test.com`

I try to pass variables by this solution below but It's show as string "$(curl http://test.com)" how to solve it

```
.test
  variables:
     SERVER : $(curl http://test.com)
```

Answer (score 3):

As [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72624596/6309), you can try and assign the variable in a before_script step:

```yaml
before_script:
  - export SERVER=$(cat .nvmrc)
```

Then you can use `$SERVER` in other steps of your pipeline.

That was also suggested in [issue 34202](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/34202#note_390007586) (Allow setting variable to a contents of a file).